# "Экстремальный", но "экстрим"

Tags: орфография

Я все время спотыкаюсь на этом слове. Знаю, что правильно "экстрЕмальный", но так и хочется проверить его словом "экстрим". Впрочем, есть и слово "экстремум".
Откуда вообще взялся этот "экстрим"? Слово-то не русское.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экстрим - это сленговое словечко, находящееся за пределами литературного языка
Такая же ситуация со словом "игнор", которым иногда пытаются объяснить правописание слова "игнорировать". На самом деле слово "игнорировать" - непроверяемое, словарное слово

Comment: ха. Это *пока* - оно сленговое... Подождите, ещё придёт время, когда вторую гласную в слове *игнорировать* будут проверять словом *игнор* :-)